# How does the Linux kernel know the computer architecture?

Tags: linux-kernel, init, cpu-architecture

In `start_kernel()`, one of the first things the kernel does is run `setup_arch()`. `setup_arch()` is defined for every supported architecture, so it is passed a pointer to the appropriate command line.

How is this pointer initialized, and how and when does the kernel get the architecture of the computer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A given kernel is built for a single architecture, so it has a single implementation of `setup_arch`. [The generic `start_kernel`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.12/source/init/main.c#L852) calls that, but it doesn’t pass an initialised pointer to the command line, it passes a pointer to a pointer to the command line, and it’s part of `setup_arch`’s job to initialise that pointer.

For example, [x86 has a global `command_line` variable](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.12/source/arch/x86/kernel/setup.c#L164), and its `setup_arch` [stores its address in the pointer provided by `start_kernel`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.12/source/arch/x86/kernel/setup.c#L901).

So the kernel effectively gets the architecture of the computer when it’s built.